# App crashes when google map v2 is displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, out-of-memory, google-maps-android-api-2

I have used Google maps version 2 in my application . In some devices randomly App crashes particularly when google maps show up . Below is the stack trace when the App crashes .Please if some can advice how we can resolve it ?

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
   at com.OilBlackGold.RoutePath.onCreate(RoutePath.java:106)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
   ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
   ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3492)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:469)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
   ... 28 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` using images?

Comment: yes, but they are not that huge size that it leads to an out of memory error.

Comment: post the relevant java code and the xml layout code

Comment: can you provide me your email ID, so i can mail you...

Comment: nope i can't. then why did you post it on stackoverflow?

Comment: Please post your layout code or java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs due to an `OutOfMemoryError`.

You're probably loading large drawables as Markers(?).
Inflating smaller icons might fix the issue.